# Is there any free opensource (GNU GPL, LGPL etc) Comet Video Chat? (PHP)

Tags: php, video, comet, chat

Is there any free opensource (GNU GPL, LGPL etc) Comet Video Chat? (PHP)

I want to integrate it into my own CMS I am creating.

Comment: Doesn't sound very programming-ish, are you looking to work on something like this?

Comment: Ofcourse! I am going to integrate it into my own CMS I am creating!)

Comment: Hi. Did you were able to set up a chat roulette ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter how comet'ish it's done, you don't want real time video going through your CMS!

A better solution involves [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/), there are several high performace OSS servers that you could integrate with your web app, and also several OSS [clients](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml), some of them can be embedded on a webpage.

if you want to pass all text chat through your CMS, maybe you could pop a video-only channel through XMPP, and a comet-based text chat.  the challenge would be making those seamless.... i still think it's easier to go full XMPP, and read the server logs into the CMS.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 0):

You could start which the source code of the [ChatRoulette Clone](http://www.chatroulette-clone.com/), although it's not PHP nor an opensource product (the source code costs $99).

You definitively don't want a video chat app in PHP, unless you've got some million bucks to spend on bandwidth. Most existing products use the peer-to-peer facilities available in recent versions of Flash (so the video goes from client X to client Y, directly, without passing thru your server and without costing you a dime).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to integrate live chat to my facebook style chat app for jquery and found this:

http://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/

It is LGPL so is free and can do peer to peer video calls.